# Gatsby-remark-images is sporadically linking images

Tags: reactjs, image, frontend, gatsby

I have a file structure like so:

```
src
- images
- - blog-images
- - - (various png and jpg files)
- pages
- - blog
- - - (various .md files)
```

I successfully created the blog pages through with a template. I cannot figure out how to make these images appear. I have included gatsby-remark-images and modified by gatsby-config.js to appear like this:

```
plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `blogImages`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images/blog-images`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `blog`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pages`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/Favicon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-typography`,
      options: {
        pathToConfigModule: `src/utils/typography`,
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: 1200
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
```

Occasionally, the image will show up as I move it from the blog-images folder to images or the pages/blog folder. But then I try to adjust it or get a second image on the page working by moving it and it stops working. I undo what broke the image and it does not come back.

I've tried following [this post](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/working-with-images-in-markdown/) and [this one](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-remark-images/), but I'm not any closer to understanding what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Moments after posting, I figured it out.

I was trying to reference the image via `[alt](./filename.png)` or `[alt](./blog-images/filename.png)`. I ended up referencing it relative to the post, instead of any of my image-centric gatsby-source-filesystem configs.

What worked was `[alt](../../images/blog-images/filename.png)`